# Xtabays: Help make sense of inconsistent wording

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, saving-throw

The text for Xtabays' two special abilities is as follows in both [the official](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary2/xtabay.html) and [3rd-party](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/plants/xtabay) online SRDs:

> **Devour (Ex)** While a creature is under the effects of a xtabay's
>   soporific pollen, the plant may, as a full-round action, occupy the
>   same square as the sleeping creature and slowly sap the life from it.
>   Every round the xtabay uses this ability, the affected creature must
>   make a DC 14 Fortitude save or take 1d2 Con damage. This feeding is
>   curiously painless, and normally isn't enough to waken a foe put to
>   sleep by the plant. Each round this feeding continues, the sleeping
>   victim can attempt a new DC 14 Will save to awaken. This save DC is
>   Constitution-based.
>
> **Soporific Pollen (Ex)** As a standard action, a
>   xtabay can release sleep-inducing pollen into the air around it. Each
>   creature within a 10-ft.-radius burst centered on the xtabay must make
>   a DC 14 Will save or fall asleep for 1d3 minutes. A creature that
>   succeeds on the Fortitude save cannot be affected by the same xtabay's
>   soporific pollen for 24 hours. A creature put to sleep by this pollen
>   can be awakened by vigorously shaking the sleeper (a standard action)
>   or by damaging it. This is a mind-affecting sleep effect. The save DC
>   is Constitution-based.

Each ability makes reference to both a will save and a fortitude save, but in crossed order.  If I'm to take the above text as RAW, if you succeed at the Fortitude save to not be digested, you become immune to the pollen for 24 hours, and the "painless" feeding that "normally isn't enough to waken a foe" gives you Will saves to wake up.

I can't make heads nor tails of this.

Comment: How official is that source? Definitely seems like an editing error to me.

Comment: For reference, the wording is identical in the original source (*PFRPG Bestiary 2*).

Comment: How does one pronounce *xtabay*? (I'm imagining the *x* is an *sh* but *shtabay* sounds like something *South Park*'s Cartman would say when his PC swords a monster.)

Comment: I read it as Ex-ta-bay, but I don't have any official source for that, just my own guess based on similar words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me it reads as a typo in Soporific Pollen, as that only calls for a Will save, not any fort save but references a fort save that was never called for.

As written **Devour** only works on targets that are victim of **Soporific Pollen**. The Will saves are different ones for different aims. Assuming the typo as described above, this would make the correct order:

1. **Soporific Pollen**: Will Save to negate falling asleep, success means becoming immune to the Soporific Polllen ability of the Xtabay that used it.
2. Target needs to be asleep from any Xtabay's Pollen and the Xtabay has to be on the Square with the sleeping target:

   2. **Devour** is handled by 2 rolls:

      - Fort Save to negate 1d2 Con Damage
      - Will Save to awake

Comment: Interesting.  Does that imply that a successful will save to awaken does _not_ make you immune to the pollen?

And, does that make the text about the feeding being painless purely incorrect flavor text?

Comment: it is a save on a different ability, so yes, it is a different save and would not make you immune to the other ability.